# Issue while opening headless chrome in remote jenkins server using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, remote-server, browser-automation

I am having trouble in using headless chrome on jenkins remote server. the test is failed at the time of url invoking or takes to much of a time like 5+mins and test failed as it wont have waiting time for that long, i have tried different chromeoption like disable gpu, nosandbox etc still the issue is not solved.There is no issue in opening those url in normal mode but its not working on headless mode. i am using this chromeoptions for test:

````
enter code here
       ``` chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1366,768");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox", "--disable-infobars", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-browser-side-navigation",
                    "--ignore-certificate-errors");```
````

Comment: I have to use  headless on my selenium test  due to resolution issue on normal mode on remote server and headless chrome is started fine but in a cases like when i send credential and hit login button it takes so much time to load to dashboard page even fails most of the time

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) what version of selenium are you using ? 2) is the jenkins agent windows, linux or mac 3) does the jenkins agent os version cater for the browser version you are testing against ( we had an issue when testing on centos 6 that as newer Firefox versions had a GTK3 requirement which could not be installed and similar for Chrome, so we had to move to centos7 & 8)

Comment: Hi, djmonki  I am using selenium 3(3.8.1 to be precise ) and my jenkins server os is based on windows(Windows server 2016,Windows server 2008). So i have  issue of fixed resolution (1036,768) running test on normal window and in case of headless testing it is not working at the phase of url invoking